# pysvn get latest revision number for specific directory (not head)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysvn

I'm trying to find the latest revision number for a specific directory in the svn root, without needing to create a working copy. I know many applications can do this, but I need to get the info programatically with python.

I have tried:

```
myUrl = "https://user@svnBranch/mydir"    
rev = client.info(myUrl).revision.number
```

and it tells me that this isn't a working copy.

I tried:

```
myUrl = "https://user@svnBranch/mydir"
rev = client.revpropget("revision", url=myUrl)[0].number
```

and it gives me the head revsion number of the repository not the latest version in the specific directory.

A couple of other methods I have tried give me the same issues.

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (Lord Gamez solution did not work for me).

I solved it with:

```
svnrev = client.info2(WORKING_COPY_DIR)[0][1]['last_changed_rev'].number
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I solved it with pysvn client's info2 function:

```
def get_revision_number_of_directory(self, localPath):
    head_rev = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head)
    info = self.__client.info2(localPath, revision=head_rev, recurse=False)
    return info[0][1]['rev'].number
```

Comment: I applaud your patience in digging out the proper parameters to make it work. Thanks. I'll give it a go later today or on Monday and give you the coveted 'check' when I see it work (like I'm sure it will).