# pysvn: How to get revision number?

Tags: python, pysvn

Using [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html) to handle my SVN source repository via Python.

```
path="C:/myrepository"
client = pysvn.Client()
revision = client.update(path)
```

How can I print `revision` number?

This doesn't work:
   `print "updated to revision %d" % revision.number`

`Revision` documentation [here](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_revision).

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243790/pysvn-get-latest-revision-number-for-specific-directory-not-head) will help.

Comment: Thanks, this works (from the link above): `svnrev = self.client.info2(path)[0][1]['last_changed_rev'].number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
print "Revision: ", str(rev[0]).split(" ")[-1][:-1]
```

Revision is returned as a list containing a formatted string. The above code tokenizes the string and retrieves the revision number as the last token of the string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The number is in the rev object as an attribute. See my answer.

Comment: That's the solution, I wanted to avoid. @BarryScott 's solution saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

The value is available as a integer in the .number attribute as you expected.

Given you did not include the error I am going to guess at the problem.

However depending on the settings of Client().commit_info_style the return value from update() is changed. It can be a list of dict or udpate details for example.

See http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_variables for the details.

Barry Scott author pysvn.

Comment: You can access attributes using the dot operator like so:  `client.info(localPath).revision.number`